# Create an order for a specific customer

Tags: commerce

I'm new to commerce, but I can't find a way to generate an order for a already existing customer via Admin Panel. Do I have to code that by myself or am I missing something?

I've tried to use [Commerce Admin Advanced Order Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_admin_order_advanced) but this only seems to work with drupal users, not commerce customers.

Comment: No, just select the relevant existing customer as the order owner when you create it (commerce customers _are_ Drupal users, no difference there; if you look at the [schema for customer profiles](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21customer%21commerce_customer.install/function/commerce_customer_schema/7) you'll see `uid` is used, which is the Drupal user id for the profile)

Comment: Then something went wrong with my import. Because my customers aren't Drupal users. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have it set up to create a new account or so you allow anonymous checkout only. If the latter, your profiles probably all relate to the anonymous user (uid 0)

Comment: Where can I set up that a new account is created for every customer? I'm working with Commerce Feeds, but can't get it to creating drupal accounts next to customers.

Comment: Just a clarification on the customer profile thing. Customer profiles are *not* users, they belong to a user, and that uid property is reflecting that. A customer profile is assigned to an existing user and a user might have multiple profiles.

Comment: Now I begin to understand that connection. I thought users and customers where the same and thought something went wrong with my import. The customer-import is kind of useless then, cause I can't do anything with customers at all :( need to generate drupal-users first, right? Damn thing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to create the order that you want until the step that you want with your admin/webmaster/whatever role that has enough permissions and then, edit the order and change the owner.

If you create an order so the customer can pay it, you just send them the checkout url, as you changed the owner, they will have access to finish the checkout.

If you process the payment as well, you need an extra step of configuration, in order to send the customer a proper notification that the order was made. Rules is a good way to do this.